# How to add an installed ruby or jruby version to rbenv

Tags: ruby, jruby, rbenv

I am trying to set up a jruby environment with rbenv on a box that doesn't have an internet connection. I sucessfully managed to install jruby in `/opt/jruby-1.7.11` but don't know to make rbenv recognize that installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a symlink to your installed jruby version from within `~/.rbenv/versions/` for rbenv to  recognize it.

Comment: Did not work for me. I re-installed jruby using rbenv. That worked.